# Mips-running a program using simple commands

Tags: mips

I tried to run this program and still have issue with the output I want it to be 6

```
######### Main method ######### 
.data
promptA: .asciiz "Please enter an integer (a):\n"
promptB: .asciiz "Please enter an integer (b):\n"
gcd:     .asciiz "gcd(" 
endPar:  .asciiz ")" 
comma:   .asciiz "," 
equals:  .asciiz ") = "
times2:  .asciiz " *(2^" 
.text
jal getIntegersAandB   #save a and b   
add $s0, $v0, $0  #save a into $s0
add $s1, $v1, $0  #save b into $s1   #move integers a and b into argument registers
add $a0, $v0, $0  #move integer a to $a0  
add $a1, $v1, $0  #move integer b to $a1 
jal getGCD   #save g and d  
add $s2, $v0, $0  #save g into $s2 
add $s3, $v1, $0  #save d into $s3   #move a, b, g, d into argument registers
add $a0, $s0, $0  #move a to a0  
add $a1, $s1, $0  #move b to a1  
add $a2, $s2, $0  #move g to a2 
add $a3, $s3, $0  #move d to a3 
jal print  
j   exit 
########## getIntegersAandB method ######### 
getIntegersAandB:        #set up stack pointer 
addi $sp, $sp, -4     #allocate stack frame of 4 bytes 
sw   $ra, 0($sp)      #save return address       #get integer A    
la   $a0, promptA     # load address of prompt for syscall   
li   $v0, 4           # specify Print String service  
syscall               # print the promptA string  
li   $v0, 5           # specify Read Integer service, 5 is to read integers   
syscall               # Read the number. After this instruction, the number read is in $v0.  
add $t0, $v0, $zero   # transfer the number to the desired register        #get integer B
la   $a0, promptB     # load address of prompt for syscall  
li   $v0, 4           # specify Print String service    
syscall               # print the promptB string     
li   $v0, 5           # specify Read Integer service, 5 is to read integers  
syscall               # Read the number. After this instruction, the number read is in $v0.    
add $t1, $v0, $zero   # transfer the number to the desired register    #put a and b into return variables
add $v0, $t0, $zero   #transfer a to the return variable $v0  
add $v1, $t1, $zero   #transfer b to the return variable $v1       #restore stack    
lw   $ra, 0($sp)      #restore return address   
addi $sp, $sp, 4      #free stack frame       #return to caller     
jr $ra                #return to caller 
############# getGCD method ############# 
getGCD:       #set up stack   
addi $sp, $sp, -4     #allocate stack frame of 4 bytes   
sw   $ra, 0($sp)      #save return address       #gcd binary algorithm   
add $v1, $0, $0       #set d = 0       #while a and b are both even do 
loop: and $t1, $a0, 0x01    #check if a is even ($t1 = 0 even otherwise odd)    
and $t2, $a1, 0x01    #check if b is even ($t2 = 0 even otherwise odd)   
seq $t3, $t1, $0      #is a even?     
seq $t4, $t2, $0      #is b even?  
and $t5, $t3, $t4     #is both a and b even?   
bne $t5, 1, nextloop  #if both a and b are not even, then go to next loop   
sra $a0, $a0, 1       #a/2  
sra $a1, $a1, 1       #b/2    
add $v1, $v1, 1       #d = d + 1   
j   loop       #while a != b do 
nextloop:   
beq $a0, $a1, output  # if a == b      
and $t1, $a0, 0x01    #check if a is even ($t1 = 0 even otherwise odd) 
and $t2, $a1, 0x01    #check if b is even ($t2 = 0 even otherwise odd) 
sle $t3, $a0, $a1     #set if a <= b  ($t3= 0 if a>b otherwise 1)       #if a is even then a = a/2 
aIsEven:       bne $t1, $0, bIsEven  #if a is even continue, otherwise go to next if 
sra $a0, $a0, 1       #a/2  
j nextloop       #else if b is even then b = b/2
bIsEven:       bne $t2, $0, aGTb     #if b is even continue, otherwise go to next if  
sra $a1, $a1, 1       #b/2  
j nextloop       #else if a > b then a = (a-b)/2 
aGTb:       bne $t3, $0, else   #if a > b continue, otherwise go to else   
sub $a0, $a0, $a1   #a-b   
sra $a0, $a0, 1     #(a-b)/2  
j nextloop       #else b = (b-a)/2 
else:       sub $a1, $a1, $a0  # b - a     
sra $a1, $a1, 1    #(b-a)/2      
j nextloop 
output:   
add $v0, $a0, $0    #g = a put it as a return       #restore stack     
lw   $ra, 0($sp)  #restore return address   
addi $sp, $sp, 4  #free stack frame       #return to caller    
jr $ra            #return to caller 
############ print method ############### 
print:       #set up stack    
addi $sp, $sp, -4     #allocate stack frame of 4 bytes     
sw   $ra, 0($sp)      #save return address       #store arguments    
add   $t0, $a0, $0   #a      
add   $t1, $a1, $0   #b     
add   $t2, $a2, $0   #g   
add   $t3, $a3, $0   #d       #print gcd(a, b) = g *(2^d) 
la    $a0, gcd        #load a "gcd(" as an argument for printing
li    $v0, 4          #ask for print service 
syscall               #prints a "gcd("     
add   $a0, $t0, $0    #load a to a0    
li    $v0, 1          #ask integer print service  
syscall               #prints a          
la    $a0, comma     #load "," to a0 
li    $v0, 4         #ask string print service  
syscall              #print ","         
add   $a0, $t1, $0   #load b to a0  
li    $v0, 1         #ask integer print service    
syscall              #print b             
la    $a0, equals    #load ") = " to a0    
li    $v0, 4         #ask string print service   
syscall              #print ") = "           
add   $a0, $t2, $0   #load g to a0                         
li    $v0, 1         #ask integer print service 
syscall              #print g          
la    $a0, times2    #load " *(2^" to a0     
li    $v0, 4         #ask string print service 
syscall              #print " *(2^"      
add   $a0, $t3, $0   #load d into a0   
li    $v0, 1         #ask integer print service   
syscall              #print d          
la    $a0, endPar    #load ")" into a0   
li    $v0, 4         #ask string print service  
syscall                            #restore stack    
lw   $ra, 0($sp)  #restore return address     
addi $sp, $sp, 4  #free stack frame       #return to caller  
jr $ra            #return to caller      
exit:
```

I am expecting the output to be 6

**QUESTION**

One method for computing the greatest common divisor of two positive numbers is the binary gcd method, which uses only subtraction and division by 2. The algorithm of the binary gcd is outlined below:

```
Input: a, b positive integers
Output: g and d such that g is odd and gcd(a, b) = g×2d
d = 0
 while (a and b are both even) {
 a = a/2
 b = b/2
 d = d + 1
 }
 while (a != b) {
 if (a is even) a = a/2
 else if (b is even) b = b/2
 else if (a > b) a = (a – b)/2
 else b = (b – a)/2
 }
g = a
```

Write a program that asks the user to enter two positive numbers a and b and outputs the greatest common divisor of the two numbers by implementing the given algorithm. If the user enters a=48 and b=18, your program should output the gcd as 6.

Comment: When the program output wasn't 6, did you try anything to debug the problem? Usually, that's the first step, then ask when your debugging efforts are exhausted. You can then enumerate all of the debugging attempts you tried and what you discovered in each one, asking a [specific technical question](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: Hi ggorlen yes I did try, it would just print  3 *(2^1) which is something equal to 6 yet I want only 6 alone so I tried multiple things and failed so I asked here.

Comment: First, verify that the psedocode works as expected and that you understand how it works. Then debug the assembly, by comparing with the pseudo code at each step in the program.  Don't just let it run and note that it answers/outputs wrong: watch & verify line by line.